# Map values are in array. All the values need to be converted to list and combine all as a result list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map with an Array as values. Now all this array need to be converted to list. at last, all the list should be combined as a single list.

Available now,

```
Map<String, Class1[]> master_map= new HashMap<>();

Class1 c1 = new Class("Name1", "Address1");
Class1 c2 = new Class("Name2", "Address2");
ClassArray[0] = c1;
ClassArray[1]= c2;
master_map.put("FirstValue", ClassArray);

Class1 c3 = new Class("Name3", "Address3");
Class1 c4 = new Class("Name4", "Address4");
ClassArray[0] = c3;
ClassArray[1]= c4;
master_map.put("SecondValue", ClassArray);}
```

Now I like to have the result as follows.

```
List<Class1> result  = new ArrayList<>();
//This above list to be as {c1, c2, c3, c4}
```

Expect the code in java8

Comment: Not really sure but were you just looking for `Arrays.asList(classArray)`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to flatten your inner arrays in the stream of entries:

```
List<Class1> result = master_map.values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream) //use flatMap to flatten nested stream
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the map using entry set and for each value(i.e. array) you can use Arrays.asList to convert it into list and add that in your final list.

```
    Map<String , Integer[]> hm = new HashMap<String,Integer[]>();
    List<Integer> finalList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(Entry<String, Integer[]> entry:hm.entrySet()) {
        finalList.addAll(Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()));
    }
```

with use of parallel streams it can be done like this

```
    Map<String , Integer[]> hm = new HashMap<String,Integer[]>();

    List<Integer> finalList = hm.values().parallelStream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

This is simple example with integer array. You can refer this and to arrive at your solution.

Answer (score 0):

And another Java 8 simple variant:

```
List<Class1> result  = new ArrayList<>();
master_map.entrySet().stream().forEach(element -> {
  result.addAll(Arrays.asList(element.getValue()));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example

```
    List<Class1> x = new ArrayList<>();
    master_map.forEach((k,v) -> x.addAll(Arrays.asList(v)));
```

Comment: you must have realized that you really don't need the keys `k` there, so maybe just iterate over the values somehow would clean that?